# Android/GoogleDrive Pictures upload

Tags: java, android, google-drive-android-api

First i'm a french student so forgive my english..

I have started an app which takes photos and now I want it to save thoses photos on GoogleDrive. I followed the Google tutorial and I now have a mistake that I can't explain and I don't know how to solve it :

400 Bad Request
{
"code":400,
"errors":[{
"domain": "global",
"location": "fields",
"locationType": "parameter",
"message": "Invalid field selection items",
"reason": "invalidParameter"
}],
"message": "Invalid field selection items"
}

This link may help https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors even if I don't really understand how it is suppose to help.

Of course, I did everything that google asked : https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart/android

This is the activity in which there is the error.

I hope you will understand my problem and if you do and help to solve it I just have to say thank you (even if you just read)..

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException;

import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.ExponentialBackOff;

import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;

import com.google.api.services.drive.model.*;

import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;

public class DriveActivity extends Activity {
GoogleAccountCredential mCredential;
private TextView mOutputText;
ProgressDialog mProgress;

static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1000;
static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1001;
static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 1002;
private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";
private static final String[] SCOPES = { DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY };

/**
 * Create the main activity.
 * @param savedInstanceState previously saved instance data.
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout activityLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    activityLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
    activityLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    activityLayout.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams tlp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    mOutputText = new TextView(this);
    mOutputText.setLayoutParams(tlp);
    mOutputText.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);
    mOutputText.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    mOutputText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    activityLayout.addView(mOutputText);

    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgress.setMessage("Connexion Google Drive ...");

    setContentView(activityLayout);

    // Initialize credentials and service object.
    SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
            .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff())
            .setSelectedAccountName(settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null));
}


/**
 * Called whenever this activity is pushed to the foreground, such as after
 * a call to onCreate().
 */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        refreshResults();
    } else {
        mOutputText.setText("Google Play Services requièrent: " +
                "après l'installation, fermer et relancer l'app.");
    }
}

/**
 * Called when an activity launched here (specifically, AccountPicker
 * and authorization) exits, giving you the requestCode you started it with,
 * the resultCode it returned, and any additional data from it.
 * @param requestCode code indicating which activity result is incoming.
 * @param resultCode code indicating the result of the incoming
 *     activity result.
 * @param data Intent (containing result data) returned by incoming
 *     activity result.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(
        int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES:
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                isGooglePlayServicesAvailable();
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null &&
                    data.getExtras() != null) {
                String accountName =
                        data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                if (accountName != null) {
                    mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                    SharedPreferences settings =
                            getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                    editor.apply();
                }
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                mOutputText.setText("Compte non spécifié.");
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                chooseAccount();
            }
            break;
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

/**
 * Attempt to get a set of data from the Drive API to display. If the
 * email address isn't known yet, then call chooseAccount() method so the
 * user can pick an account.
 */
private void refreshResults() {
    if (mCredential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
        chooseAccount();
    } else {
        if (isDeviceOnline()) {
            new MakeRequestTask(mCredential).execute();
        } else {
            mOutputText.setText("Pas de connexion internet.");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Starts an activity in Google Play Services so the user can pick an
 * account.
 */
private void chooseAccount() {
    startActivityForResult(
            mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
}

/**
 * Checks whether the device currently has a network connection.
 * @return true if the device has a network connection, false otherwise.
 */
private boolean isDeviceOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
}

/**
 * Check that Google Play services APK is installed and up to date. Will
 * launch an error dialog for the user to update Google Play Services if
 * possible.
 * @return true if Google Play Services is available and up to
 *     date on this device; false otherwise.
 */
private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    final int connectionStatusCode =
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(connectionStatusCode)) {
        showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode);
        return false;
    } else if (connectionStatusCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Display an error dialog showing that Google Play Services is missing
 * or out of date.
 * @param connectionStatusCode code describing the presence (or lack of)
 *     Google Play Services on this device.
 */
void showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
        final int connectionStatusCode) {
    Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
            connectionStatusCode,
            DriveActivity.this,
            REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
    dialog.show();
}

/**
 * An asynchronous task that handles the Drive API call.
 * Placing the API calls in their own task ensures the UI stays responsive.
 */
private class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
    private com.google.api.services.drive.Drive mService = null;
    private Exception mLastError = null;

    public MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
        HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        mService = new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("AthexisPics")
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Background task to call Drive API.
     * @param params no parameters needed for this task.
     */
    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            return getDataFromApi();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mLastError = e;
            cancel(true);
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fetch a list of up to 10 file names and IDs.
     * @return List of Strings describing files, or an empty list if no files
     *         found.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
        // Get a list of up to 10 files.
        List<String> fileInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
        FileList result = mService.files().list()
                .setPageSize(10)
                .setFields("nextPageToken, items(id, name)")
                .execute();
        List<File> files = result.getFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                fileInfo.add(String.format("%s (%s)\n",
                        file.getName(), file.getId()));
            }
        }
        return fileInfo;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mOutputText.setText("");
        mProgress.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> output) {
        mProgress.hide();
        if (output == null || output.size() == 0) {
            mOutputText.setText("Pas de résultats trouvés.");
        } else {
            output.add(0, "Données récupérées:");
            mOutputText.setText(TextUtils.join("\n", output));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mProgress.hide();
        if (mLastError != null) {
            if (mLastError instanceof GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) {
                showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
                        ((GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) mLastError)
                                .getConnectionStatusCode());
            } else if (mLastError instanceof UserRecoverableAuthIOException) {
                startActivityForResult(
                        ((UserRecoverableAuthIOException) mLastError).getIntent(),
                        DriveActivity.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
            } else {
                mOutputText.setText("L'erreur suivante vient de se produire:\n"
                        + mLastError.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            mOutputText.setText("Requête annulée.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I think you are mixing two separate APIs.
1. Google Drive Android API, which the quickstart link uses. (https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro)

2. The Drive Rest API which your code seems to be using (https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk).

Comment: @Miguil Pailot : Did you get solution ?

Comment: Yes, after some others tries it finally works! I don't have any idea why the errors comes and how it disapears!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dude, I figured it out!

Same error message was displayed to me while running sample code for Rest Api for Drive in Android.

The Error Message "Invalid field selection items" means that field `item`' is not recognized by the API. Actually the name of field must have been changed in API code, without corresponding changes in sample code (Bad Google).

So in your code, instead of this line:

```
setFields("nextPageToken, items(id, name)")
```

Try this line with changed field names:

```
setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
```

Apart from items <---> files, title(as given in [online docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/performance#partial-response)) <---> name.

Again, bad Google.

Comment: This should be the correct answer! Saved my day, thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why Google puts incorrect code in its demos- it makes no sense to me. Thank you so much for the solution!

Comment: Thank you. In addition to `items` being renamed to `files`, it seems `title` was renamed to `name` too

Answer (score 0):

Based on the  [Official Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors) the *400 'invalidParameter'* means that a required field or parameter has not been provided, the value supplied is invalid or the combination of provided fields is invalid. Double check the parameter and value being set.

Here's a sample Demo app which takes photos and save them in Drive: https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart

Comment: thanks for your response! But this is the demo i did and i have the error with it and i already see the google doc but i never have to complete any fields with the demo. So what am i suppose to do now?